# Checking values in array MongoDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I need to check if a value is not in an array in MongoDB. This should happen together with two other checks connected with `$and`.
Here is my code:

```
Meteor.users.findOne({$and:[{"profile.assigned":"somevalue"},
                             {_id: {$ne: someoneId} },
                 {"the array": {the value which should not be in the array} }
                                    ]});
```

Which is the correct syntax to do that query. I noticed some questions here but I could not find something related to my problem. I should query a specific array which is a property of the user and contains some other id's.